# Kendo Area Chart - Can't get smooth area style to work like example

Tags: telerik, kendo-dataviz

Following the Telerik Kendo Area Chart example found here: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dataviz/area-charts/index.html

I've been trying to apply the 'smooth' effect to my chart, but with no luck.

```
seriesDefaults: {
                type: "area",
                stack:false,
                area: {
                    line: {
                        style: "smooth"
                    }
                }
            },
```

Maybe I'm going blind, but I can't see what's wrong.. I've tried a myriad of different options and included all of the css styles for example in the jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/markive/u33m6/

Any idea what I am doing wrong?